# export gmail with 40,000 mails to pst/exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, exchange

i enabled a few years ago the IMAP & POP3 options, since that i got about 40,000 messages, i want to move now to hosted exchange and im looking how to move all the old emails from gmail to there, is this possible?

Comment: What application is storing the emails right now? Outlook does have an import feature. You might be able to export in whatever application you are using now and import that into Outlook. If you are looking to get the emails moved to the actual server and not hosted locally, then you will not be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the Gmail IMAP account to Outlook. Then you could copy the mail from e.g. the Gmail inbox to your Exchange account inbox in Outlook. Perhaps a bit time consuming but it worked for me when copying from Gmail to a local account.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this tool several times to download Google mail to a local machine's hard drive.

You could then hopefully import the messages into Exchange (I don't know much about Exchange unfortunately)

http://www.gmail-backup.com/